# Target specific div Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I Want to target a div using jQuery and change its color of innerHtml to red having INACTIVE Status (It is basically a select2 box)

This is the jQuery code  I have so far to target that div:

```
$("div#select2-drop ul > li > div:contains(INACTIVE)").css('color','red');
```

[image: I Want to target that div using jquery and change its color of innerHtml to red having INACTIVE Status]

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried to achieve your requirement and mention the issues you are facing

Comment: This is Jquery code i have written so far to target that div

`$("div#select2-drop ul > li > div:contains(INACTIVE)").css('color','red');`

Comment: which is? please post what you have written in your question. Much better if you can create a demo using stack snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: what is that inactive status? You want the change the color of the text or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have per your comments `$("div#select2-drop ul > li > div:contains(INACTIVE)").css('color','red');`

This targets an element with an ID however you have a class.

Use the class selector.

```
$("div.select2-drop")
 .find("ul > li")
 .find("div:contains('INACTIVE')").css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **:contains() Selector** example at: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/#entry-examples

`$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );`

Your `div:contains(INACTIVE)` should be `div:contains('INACTIVE')` to find all divs containing "INACTIVE"